# Javascript: tracing custom events

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, trace, backbone-events

Is there a way to trace custom events, specially those non-DOM events like in backbone?

```
thisObj.on("custom:triggeredEvents", function() { do.stuffHere() });
thisObj.trigger("custom:triggeredEvents");
```

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean by trace here?

Comment: something like console.trace();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

If you don't want to implement this by yourself, you can use existing libraries, e.g. https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS